# Does insect repellant protect against Covid-19?

Tags: covid-19, government

[The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/aug/26/citriodiol-based-spray-can-help-protect-against-covid-19-says-mod-lab) reported on 26 August 2020 that :

> Citriodiol-based spray can help protect against Covid-19, says MoD lab

Citriodiol sprays were made available to the army in the early phases of the Covid-19 crisis because they were known to kill other strains of coronavirus such as Sars.

> The Ministry of Defence released an eight-page paper from the Porton Down-based Defence Science and Technology Lab (DSTL), which tested the efficacy of Mosi-guard, a Citriodiol-based spray, on plastic and artificial skin.

> Jeremy Quin, a junior defence minister, said the research found that sprays containing Citriodiol “can kill the virus”.

Confusingly, the article further says that the DSTL laboratory also states :

> However, some virus was still recoverable over a four-hour period.

Is mosquito repellant actually effective or is it not ?

Comment: The title asks about "protection", the final question is about "effective".  I don't see any claim about either of those presented in the article, only some reduction in virus.

Comment: @BowlOfRed _Jeremy Quin, a junior defence minister, said the research found that sprays containing Citriodiol “can kill the virus”_

Comment: The claim in the Guardian is a bit murky (the headline writer (and perhaps the first paragraph)  over-states what the writer has written throughout the rest of the article) but it seems to be "Yes, it killed *some* of the virus, but it isn't clear if it is enough to make a difference in practice." Your question demands an answer to a claim that isn't being made, because it is unknown: Is it protective? Is it effective?

Comment: ... so it's better to ask this on https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/ which doesn't require a clear-cut claim to challenge.

Comment: Or learn to accept that some things just aren't known yet, and it is okay to not be sure. Come back in 6-12 months and maybe there will be answers.